# set default value of attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to set the default value for an attribute `initial_collection_amount` to a calculation which is based off another attribute `amount`. `initial_collection_amount` is nil until the record has been persisted, so `after_create` triggers a validation error:

```
after_create :set_initial_collection_amount
def set_initial_collection_amount
 self.initial_collection_amount ||= self.amount * 0.15
end
```

That results in something like `initial_collection_amount cannot be blank`.

Setting `initial_collection_amount` to 0 with an `after_initialize` and then running the above `after_create` seems sloppy, and in fact doesn't even work the way I'd think it would. I added a `puts` to each for the terminal output, like so:

```
after_initialize :set_initial_collection_amount_to_0
after_create :set_initial_collection_amount_x_15
def set_initial_collection_amount_to_0
  puts "a"
  self.initial_collection_amount ||= 0
end

def set_initial_collection_amount_x_15
  puts "b"
  total = self.amount * 0.15
  self.initial_collection_amount ||= total
end
```

Terminal output from that shows the `a` in the puts statement 15 times.

How would I do this? I just want that one attribute to be saved. If I add `allow_nil: true` to the validations it just saves as blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the value set immediately before the record is created, a `before_create` event seems more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: THANKS. i'm dumb.